# why form is submitted while the return from validateform() is false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-mobile

I have the code where I have the javascript validation in jquery mobile.But the problem is the form is submitted even the validate form is return false.What may be the reason please reply? Below is my code.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Validate Contact Table
    function validateContact() {
        var emergencyContactElt = document.getElementById("Emergency_Contact");
        var emergencyContactEltRows = emergencyContactElt.rows;
        var maxrowNbr = emergencyContactElt.rows.length;
        var error = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i < maxrowNbr; i++) {
            // Validation for First Name
            if (emergencyContactEltRows[i].cells[1].children[0].children[0].value == "") {
                emergencyContactEltRows[i].cells[1].children[0].children[0].style.background = '#e35152';
                emergencyContactEltRows[i].cells[1].children[0].focus();
                error = error + 1;
            } else {
                emergencyContactEltRows[i].cells[1].children[0].children[0].style.background = 'white';
            }

            // Validation for Last Name
            if (emergencyContactEltRows[i].cells[2].children[0].children[0].value == "") {
                emergencyContactEltRows[i].cells[2].children[0].children[0].style.background = '#e35152';
                emergencyContactEltRows[i].cells[2].children[0].focus();
                error = error + 1;
            } else {
                emergencyContactEltRows[i].cells[2].children[0].children[0].style.background = 'white';
            }

            // Validation phone number
            if (emergencyContactEltRows[i].cells[3].children[0].children[0].value == "") {
                emergencyContactEltRows[i].cells[3].children[0].children[0].style.background = '#e35152';
                emergencyContactEltRows[i].cells[3].children[0].focus();
                error = error + 1;
            } else {
                emergencyContactEltRows[i].cells[3].children[0].children[0].style.background = 'white';
            }

        }

        if (error > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //Validate Form 
    function validateForm() {
        var error = 0;
        if (!validateContact()) {
            error++;
            alert("Contact");
        }

        // Don't submit form if there are errors
        if (error > 0) {
            alert(error);
            alert("highlight fields are required");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }        </script>
</head>

 <body>
  <form name="submitform" id="submitform" method="post" action="%bind(:25)" onsubmit="return validateForm();" >
  <table id="Emergency_Contact" name="Emergency_Contact">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Relationship</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
     <th>Last Name</th>
     <th>Phone</th>
     <th>Email Id</th>
     <th>Consent</th>
     <th>Working/Studying In ADU</th>
     <th>Employee Id/Student ID</th>
     <th>Add/Delete</th>
     </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <select name="Relationship" id="Relationship" class="Relationship" style="width:100%"> 
       <option value="B" selected="">Brother</option>
       <option value="D">Daughter</option>
       <option value="E">Employee</option>
       <option value="ER">Employer</option>
       <option value="ES">Ex-Spouse</option>
      </select>
     </td> 
     <td> 
      <input name="First_Name" id="First_Name" value="" style="width:100%" type="text">
     </td> 
      <input name="Last_Name" id="Last_Name" value="" style="width:100%" type="text">
     </td> 
     <td>
      <input name="Phone" value="" style="width:100%" type="text">
     </td>   
    </tr> 
   </tbody>
  </table>
   <div data-role="ui-grid-a">
              <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:50%">
     <input type="button" id="Previous" value="Previous" onclick="window.location.href='%bind(:24)'"/>
     </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:50%">
     <!--<input type="Submit" id="Submit" value="Save and Next" class="ui-btn ui-shadow"/>-->
     <input type="Submit" id="Submit" value="Save and Next" />
    </div>
   <div>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you using IE? which one?

Comment: Console errors: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined` on `if (document.getElementById("Emergency_Contact").rows[i].cells[3].children[0].children[0].value == "")`

Comment: Why not use `jQuery` as you anyway have it included?

Comment: jquery form validation will be suitable one here!! :)

Comment: You declare `var error` inside `validateForm()`, so it's only available in that scope. But you test it outside, so you will never get `if(error > 0)`.

Comment: Besides, you could probably cache `document.getElementById("Emergency_Contact").rows[i]` to avoid countless DOM accesses and cut down your code... `var element = document.getElementById("Emergency_Contact").rows[i]`...

Answer (score 1):

You have console errors. But why not use jQuery when you have it - here you no longer need the onsubmit, just add

```
.error { background-color:#e35152}
```

and have

```
$(function() {
  $("#submitform").on("submit", function(e) {
    $(this).find("input[type='text']").each(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("error", $.trim(this.value) == "");
    });
    if ($(".error").length > 0) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("highlight fields are required");
    }
  });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#submitform").on("submit", function(e) {
    $(this).find("input[type='text']").each(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("error", $.trim(this.value) == "");
    });
    if ($(".error").length > 0) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("highlight fields are required");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
 .error {
   background-color: #e35152
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="submitform" id="submitform" method="post" action="%bind(:25)">
  <table id="Emergency_Contact" name="Emergency_Contact">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Relationship</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Email Id</th>
        <th>Consent</th>
        <th>Working/Studying In ADU</th>
        <th>Employee Id/Student ID</th>
        <th>Add/Delete</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name="Relationship" id="Relationship" class="Relationship" style="width:100%">
            <option value="B" selected="">Brother</option>
            <option value="D">Daughter</option>
            <option value="E">Employee</option>
            <option value="ER">Employer</option>
            <option value="ES">Ex-Spouse</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="First_Name" id="First_Name" value="" style="width:100%" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="Last_Name" id="Last_Name" value="" style="width:100%" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="Phone" value="" style="width:100%" type="text">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div data-role="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:50%">
      <input type="button" id="Previous" value="Previous" onclick="window.location.href='%bind(:24)'" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:50%">
      <!--<input type="Submit" id="Submit" value="Save and Next" class="ui-btn ui-shadow"/>-->
      <input type="Submit" id="Submit" value="Save and Next" />
    </div>
    <div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The original issue is happening because of a missing <td> before 'last_name' input. This is causing 'validateContact' function to throw an exception.

For all simple requirements like this, it is better to use native stuff over jquery. Try to use 'querySelector' method for selecting DOM node to process.